# Issue with different values after reprojection using GDALWARP (epsg4269 -> 3857)

Tags: postgis, openlayers

I need to reproject a raster file (.tif) from EPSG 4269 to EPSG 3857 (OpenLayers default) to be used in PostGIS and tiled and served to an OpenLayers front end. I used the following command to reproject the file:

```
gdalwarp -s_srs epsg:4269 -t_srs epsg:3857 /path/to/4269_file.tif /path/to/3857_file.tif
```

When I query the data in PostGIS on both files, the values are off. I am using a location (coordinate) based lookup query. The values in the 4269 projection look accurate and the ones in the 3857 projection do not. Any ideas as to why this is happening?

GDALINFO:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Size is 117487, 76840
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCS["NAD83",
    DATUM["North_American_Datum_1983",
        SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.2572221010042,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6269"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4269"]]
Origin = (-98.535677542070658,45.199644749068938)
Pixel Size = (0.000269494585236,-0.000269494585236)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  DataType=Generic
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=LZW
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  ( -98.5356775,  45.1996447) ( 98d32' 8.44"W, 45d11'58.72"N)
Lower Left  ( -98.5356775,  24.4916808) ( 98d32' 8.44"W, 24d29'30.05"N)
Upper Right ( -66.8735672,  45.1996447) ( 66d52'24.84"W, 45d11'58.72"N)
Lower Right ( -66.8735672,  24.4916808) ( 66d52'24.84"W, 24d29'30.05"N)
Center      ( -82.7046224,  34.8456628) ( 82d42'16.64"W, 34d50'44.39"N)
Band 1 Block=128x128 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Gray
  NoData Value=255
  Metadata:
    RepresentationType=THEMATIC

Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Size is 109320, 88072
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator",
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
    PROJECTION["Mercator_1SP"],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",0],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AXIS["X",EAST],
    AXIS["Y",NORTH],
    EXTENSION["PROJ4","+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs"],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","3857"]]
Origin = (-10968941.448953511193395,5653006.415421720594168)
Pixel Size = (32.241277618252468,-32.241277618252468)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  DataType=Generic
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-10968941.449, 5653006.415) ( 98d32' 8.44"W, 45d11'58.72"N)
Lower Left  (-10968941.449, 2813452.613) ( 98d32' 8.44"W, 24d29'30.51"N)
Upper Right (-7444324.980, 5653006.415) ( 66d52'24.63"W, 45d11'58.72"N)
Lower Right (-7444324.980, 2813452.613) ( 66d52'24.63"W, 24d29'30.51"N)
Center      (-9206633.214, 4233229.514) ( 82d42'16.54"W, 35d30'31.36"N)
Band 1 Block=109320x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Gray
  NoData Value=255
  Metadata:
    RepresentationType=THEMATIC
```

Lookup query used:

```
WITH point AS (
  SELECT ST_SetSrid(ST_MakePoint(lon, lat),3857) geom
)
SELECT 
  ST_Value(a.rast, geom) AS value
FROM point p
LEFT JOIN 3857_table a ON (ST_Intersects(p.geom, a.rast))
```

Here is the command I used to import the data:

```
raster2pgsql -I -C -s 3857 /path/to/3857_file.tif -F -t 100x100 public.3857_table | psql -d PostGIS
```

Images of both queries:
[image]

[image]

Comment: This could be a datum shift issue, since 4269 is in a different datum (NAD83) than 3857 (WGS84)

Comment: Warping leads to resampling.  A new set of pixels is built from the original pixels. You can see that the size of the original is 117487, 76840 and the size of the warped image is 109320, 88072. They are not the same pixels. The default resampling method in gdalwarp is nearest neighbor that does not create new values but the value may be picked from an adjacent pixel. You wrote that values are off but not in which way they are off. Is that systematical? Other resampling methods (average, cubic) could smooth the result but they create values which do not exist in the input.

Comment: @user30184 Yes, I read about the resampling and am currently warping with the bilinear method, which might make it a little more accurate. I'm not exactly sure which ways they are off, but with the location query I am using, it returns nothing but null values when the actual data would return real values. When I run a statistics query, I can see that it holds values still, just perhaps in the wrong locations. Unfortunately, I'm not experienced enough with GIS querying to dissect and find a pattern of how the values differ.

Comment: @Vince Interesting. Is there a way to correct this with some type of constraints in the warp command?

Comment: I believe that null values are indication of some other problem. You should explain  this in more details "I am using a location (coordinate) based lookup query".

Comment: @user30184 I added the query to the description. This works perfectly on the 4269 file and not the 3857 file.

Comment: And how the GeoTIFF images were imported into PostGIS raster? Show also example of failing query with exact coordinates that you used in `ST_SetSrid(ST_MakePoint(lon, lat),3857)`.

Comment: @user30184 Check the updated description please.

Comment: Also just added screenshots of the query requests

Comment: Your ST_SetSrid with those coordinates and EPSG:3857 is placing the point pretty close to Null Island. You are still giving EPSG:4326 coordinates and SetSrid must match them. Set SRID into 4326 and re-project the point into EPSG:3857 with ST_Transform. Or give the coordinates as meters in EPSG:3857.

Comment: @user30184 I'm confused as to why I would use 4326 instead of 4269. Do you have a code example from my query code to show this? And I will be setting up a python tile server to display these tiles, will transforming the data be a viable solution with that in mind? I need to both query the data and display it on a map.

Comment: @user30184 Ah I converted the degrees to meters and it shows correct values. I didn't know this was necessary. I will have to find a conversion rate for degrees to meters.

Comment: One way to do it is `select ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('POINT (-90.526459 29.468936)',4326),3857)`. Or if you want to see the numbers then `select ST_AsText(ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('POINT (-90.526459 29.468936)',4326),3857))`.

Comment: @user30184 This does work, thank you. Do you know if there's a major performance difference between ST_GeomFromText and ST_SetSrid(ST_MakePoint())? Also, doing this conversion in the DB versus on the Python side with pyproj?

Comment: Also, if you post this as an answer, I can accept it.

Comment: ST_MakePoint is documented to be faster http://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakePoint.html but the difference is probably measured in microseconds per conversion. You can write an answer yourself. And you could also edit the title of your question, it is rather misleading now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual issue, as user30184 pointed out, is that I am trying to lookup the values using degree coordinates instead of meters, which is what the EPSG:3857 projection uses. Changing the lookup query using the following fixed my issue:

```
select ST_Transform(ST_SetSrid(ST_MakePoint(lon, lat),4269),3857)
```